# Use IBOutlets on different ViewController storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a storyboard app with two different ViewController. On the second ViewController I have a UIImageView and I would like to call that UIImageView on the first one. I've been looking for a solution but I can't find anything that work for me.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pic;
```

I just want to be able to use that UIImageView on the other viewcontroller. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

yes you can try to set your UIImageView in prepare for segue. I have tried it and it seems to work. You would do it as follows:

**I am assuming that the controller you are seguing to is called NewViewController
**I am also assuming your NewViewController has a UIImageView called imageView

```
-(void)prepareForSegue....
  {
   if ([segueIdentifier isEqual....])
       {
        NewViewController *newController=(NewViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        [[newViewController imageView]setImage:self.someUIImageFromCurrentClass];
        [[newViewController imageView]setNeedDisplay];
       }
  }
```

and yes, you do have to create a UIImage in current class (in this case it's self.someUIImageFromCurrentClass). That's the point is that you're taking an image from current ViewController (current class) and showing it in the ViewController you are seguing to.

### ORIGINAL:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"your segue name"])
     {
       [segue.destinationViewController setYourUIImage:self.someImageFromCurrentClass];
     }
}
```

be sure to import the .h file for the controller you're seguing to.

second, YourUIImage is an UIImage that is publicly declared in the controller you're seguing to (like Michael mentioned).

In the destination controller, you'll want to grab that UIImage and set it as the image for you UIImageView:

```
[self.myImageView setImage:YourUIImage]; // <-- you can do this in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear
```

that should get you going

**Also I guess it's worth mentioning is that a segue always creates a new instance of the controller you're seguing to, which doesn't exist before the segue, which is why you have to pass the image to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have a question.. If I have the UIImageView on the VC2, Do I have to put the code on the VC1? because I'm getting some errors when I mention that UIImageView.And do I have to create a UIImage on VC1 and put it on "someImageFromCurrentClass". Thanks and sorry, I kind of new on this :)

Comment: I edited my answer with more info, should clear things up more. If it helps, give it a vote up

Comment: I cannot get it working, could you please send me the project file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use outlets between view controllers (VCs) because there's no automatic one for one VC to refer to another. You'll have to expose public properties or methods that allow the manipulation you need and find some way to pass a reference to one VC from another.

For example, if you pass from one VC to another via a segue, you can manipulate properties in the destination VC from the source in `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I cannot get it working, a project file would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: The other answer already covers this quite well, so I would look there.